# Positioning input tag cursor after resizing

Tags: html, css, input

I have a simple input tag in a form element

```
<form>
    <input type="text" name="" value="">
</form>
```

I wanted the input tag to look really big. So I add this:

```
input {
    height: 300px;
}
```

However, the problem which bugs me is that **the cursor of the input tag is located exactly at the centre of the height.**

I want the cursor to be at the very top. How do I position the cursor?

Comment: how about using a `<textarea>` instead?

Comment: An `input` will only take 1 line of text (hence the cursor is vertically centered), no matter how big it is, so instead, use a `textarea`

Comment: As they said you should use a textarea tag to handle better your problem.

Comment: @user2796515 Have you tried if that works? ...if you are gonna help, make sure what you suggest will have an effect, which that won't.

Answer (score 0):

Input is a one-line thing - so there is no sence to have it larger then caret.

That's why you have a choice between two options.

- To use a large font with the `input` element:

  ```
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <form>
      <input type="text" name="" value="">
    </form>
  </div>

  <style>
    input {
      font-size: 100px;
      width: 50vw;
    }

    .input-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
  ```
- Or use `textarea`:

  ```
  <div class="textarea-wrapper">
    <textarea rows="25" cols="100"></textarea>
  </div>

  <style>
    .textarea-wrapper {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      height: 100vh;
    }

    body {
      margin: 0;
    }
  </style>
  ```